# Web3 - How to determine when a transaction has been mined?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am executing a `transfer()` function in a solidity contract, and want to know when the transaction is finished. I can get the transaction receipt immediately if the transaction is executed properly, but want a simple way of knowing when it's been mined. This is what I've tried (a bit messy):

```
deployedContract.transfer(transfer_to, transfer_value, { from:web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 200000 }, function (error, result) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log(result + ' is the TxHash')
        var test = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(result, function (error, result2) {
          if (!error) {
            if (!result2) {
              console.log('waiting for transaction to be mined....')
              console.log(result + ' is still the TxHash')
            } else {
              console.log('transaction done')
            }
          } else {
            console.error(error)
          }
        })
      } else {
        console.error(error)
      }
    })
```

This will get to the `console.log('waiting for transaction to be mined....')` part but even after the transaction is definitely mined, won't get to the `console.log('transaction done')`.

If it's relevant, when deploying a new contract I could easily see when the transaction was complete as follows - but doing the same thing isn't working for me for seeing if functions executed on a contract have completed:

```
let deployedContract = contract.new({ from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data:bytecode, gas: 1300000 }, function (error, result) {
        if (!error) {
          if (!deployedContract.address) {
            // transaction hasn't been mined yet
          } else {
            // transaction has been mined
          }
        } else { console.error(error) }
      })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version of [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html), you can use the following piece of code:

```
deployedContract.methods.transfer(transfer_to, transfer_value,).send({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 200000})
    on('transactionHash', function(hash){
        console.log("transactionHash: "+transactionHash);
    })
    .on('confirmation', function(1, receipt){
        console.log("Transaction confirmed");
    })
    .on('error', console.error);
```

PS: I have not tested this personally but as per the documentation this should work fine.

Comment: I did test this, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate process ping the affected accounts(s) to detect a difference in their account balance(s). Once you detect a difference you can notify the original client that the transaction has been mined.

```
const account_map = JSON.parse(data);
let total = 276*14;
const left = Object.keys(account_map.senders)
    .map(public_key => ({
        public_key:  public_key,
        private_key: account_map.senders[public_key],
        tx_count: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(public_key),
        balance: web3.eth.getBalance(public_key),
        balanceEth: web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(public_key))
    }))
    .reduce((memo,obj) => (memo + parseFloat(obj.balanceEth),0);

console.log('diff:',total - left);
```